# I am getting crash on the list view using volley library .

Tags: android, json, facebook, listview, android-volley

I am facing crash on the getting list view with use of volley library .

I have used login with Facebook separate . and got list view with volley library separate. But when i am integrating both then i am getting crash . I want to login with Facebook after successful login i want list view. But i am getting crash .

see in the image when i did with separate project then i am getting list view with volley library.

[image]

But after adding Facebook login. I am getting crash. Please tell me solution for same.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends     Activity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private TextView btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    User user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(MainActivity.this) != null){
            //Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogoutActivity.class);
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.comida",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton= (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email","user_friends");

        btnLogin= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();

                loginButton.performClick();

                loginButton.setPressed(true);

                loginButton.invalidate();

                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallBack);

                loginButton.setPressed(false);

                loginButton.invalidate();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                            try {
                                user = new User();
                                user.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                                user.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                user.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                user.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();
                                PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user,MainActivity.this);

                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"welcome "+user.name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewActivity.class);
                            //Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LogoutActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }

                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void     onCancel() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.comida.MainActivity;
import com.comida.R;
import com.comida.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import com.comida.app.AppController;
import com.comida.model.Movie;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://wpgmiiyrhn.localtunnel.me/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=10&page=1&sort_col=average_ratings";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }*/

}
```

adater -> CustomListAdapter.java

```
import com.comida.R;
import com.comida.app.AppController;
import com.comida.model.Movie;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import java.util.List;


public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        /*ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView)convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img);

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
        else {*/

        NetworkImageView _ImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
         _ImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
        //NetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), ImageLoader);
        /*NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);*/
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
        TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        //_ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl()))
            thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
    else
            //Log.d("KeyHash:","Neeraj");*/
        _ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (m.getThumbnailUrl().compareTo("")!=0)
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        //else{
        //thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);

            else {

                thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
                //thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bc);

        }*/


        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        // rating
        average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
        address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
        cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
        /*// genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

app ->appcontroller.java

```
import com.comida.util.LruBitmapCache;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Movie -> movie.java

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings, String area, String cuisine, String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

util -> LruBitmapCache

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;



public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

logcat ->

```
/com.comida E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.comida, PID: 7059
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comida/com.comida.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader com.comida.app.AppController.getImageLoader()' on a null object reference
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader com.comida.app.AppController.getImageLoader()' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.comida.adater.CustomListAdapter.<init>(CustomListAdapter.java:22)
                                                              at com.comida.ListViewActivity.onCreate(ListViewActivity.java:44)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-21 17:09:01.800 2971-3347/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.comida/.ListViewActivity
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.comida"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <!-- To access internet -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- To access accounts configured on device -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- To use account credentials -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.comida.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListViewActivity"
            >
        </activity>

        <!--<activity
            android:name=".LogoutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_logout" >
            </activity>-->
        <activity
            android:name="SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Try initialize the imageLoader in the adapter constructor, seems that AppController.getInstance() return null

Comment: @user6313669 check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Manifest File.

Change tag  `android:name="Your.Pakage.Name.AppController"`

**"path.to.this.class.AppController"**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="Your.Pakage.Name.AppController"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Update:

Now you are setting `actionbar properties` and getting issue.

**To fix** change `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity`

```
ListViewActivity extend AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: i have changed but Still getting crash
LOGCAT ERROR " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comida/com.comida.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference

Comment: After changes ListViewActivity extend AppCompatActivity i am not getting screen of Login with facebook . I am getting list directly.

Comment: how it is possible whats changes you have made?

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
I have changed styles.xml after extending AppCompatActivity